# AttributeError : 'dict' object has no attribute 'pencolor'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

It's my first time here and I'm new in the Python.

When I wrote this code

```py
import turtle

ws = turtle.Screen()

aTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
colors = [ "pink","yellow","blue","green","white","red"]
sketch = turtle.pen()
turtle.bgcolor("black")
for i in range(200):
    sketch.pencolor(colors[i % 6])
    sketch.width(i/100+1)
    sketch.forward(i)
    sketch.left(59)

turtle.done()
```

Then I get this error with black screen

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/wi n7/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/draw1.py", line 10, in <module>

    sketch.pencolor(colors[i % 6])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pencolor'
```

Comment: Try doing `print(sketch)`

Comment: It's a simple *typo*, you meant `sketch = turtle.Pen()` -- both `Pen()` and `pen()` exist in the turtle library but do different things.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, thanks for posting a minimal, complete example and the full error message with stack trace. That's half the battle--collecting all of the information you need to perform debugging (or provide that info to others to debug for you). The next step is to use this information to actually debug the program. I'll walk you through how I do it in detail so you can do it on your own next time on any problem you might encounter.

The error tells us that `sketch.pencolor` fails because the `sketch` is a dictionary object which has no `.pencolor` attribute. Since `.pencolor` is a `Turtle` method, you probably think `sketch` is a `Turtle` object. But printing the type just above the error line with `print(type(sketch))` or looking at the error message tells us that, indeed, `sketch` is a dictionary (`dict`). Running `print(dir(sketch))` further confirms that `pencolor` is not an attribute or method available on `dict`.

So trace the code backwards from the point of failure. How did `sketch` become a `dict` unexpectedly? Find the last (and only) assignment: `sketch = turtle.pen()`.

Looking at the [docs for the `Turtle.pen()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.pen) reveals what it returns:

> Return or set the pen’s attributes in a "pen-dictionary"

The turtle library has a somewhat odd design where methods without parameters are *getters* that return a value, while methods that have a parameter are *setters* that set properties on the turtle. You're using `.pen()` in getter mode since there are no parameters. So `sketch` is a pen-dictionary because that's the return value of `.pen()`.

It's a bit semantically confusing, because you might think you need to get a pen to draw with turtle. Think of the pen as a thing the turtle holds, but you don't touch directly, so you won't need to get the pen for just about any reason other than to see what its current properties are, or to save it to permanent storage or something like that. You'll likely only set pen properties.

Another red flag: unused variables. You took the time to create `aTurtle` but never did anything with it. Actually, this is the correct variable to be using instead of `sketch` (although in Python, the correct naming convention is snake_case, `a_turtle`).

All you need to do is remove `sketch = turtle.pen()` and use `aTurtle` everywhere `sketch` was. That's the real turtle you want to draw with.

In case there's any issue doing this (try it yourself), here's the code:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


a_turtle = Turtle()
colors = "pink", "yellow", "blue", "green", "white", "red"
Screen().bgcolor("black")

for i in range(200):
    a_turtle.pencolor(colors[i % 6])
    a_turtle.width(i / 100 + 1)
    a_turtle.forward(i)
    a_turtle.left(59)

Screen().done()
```

Comment: Or simply change `pen()` to `Pen()` and everything works fine!

Comment: Very cool to know, and I always appreciate your turtle expertise, but I don't see that in the docs, so isn't that potentially an implementation detail?

Comment: It's only mentioned in passing, "RawTurtle (alias: RawPen) defines Turtle objects ... Derived from RawTurtle is the subclass Turtle (alias: Pen), which draws ..."  It must be used in some tutorial somewhere as I see this particular case error quite often.  I assume `Pen` exists for compatibility reasons.  The term is overloaded in turtle.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Turtle has too many aliases to keep track of. Seems to run contrary to the Zen of Python: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."